# Get information from a specific Firestore document for its id in Flutter

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to get the information of a specific document by its "id" to show the information of that document.

The code that I am using for the service is this:

```
class SentenciasFireBase {
  //This is a class where I have all the services of firebase
  ...
  obtenerVacaciones(String empleado) async {
    //empleado is the document id
    return await Firestore.instance.document('Vacaciones/$empleado');
  }
  ...
}
```

And the code to display the information is this:

```
class TurnoActual_State extends State<TurnoActual>{
  ...  
  SentenciasFireBase objetoSentencias = new SentenciasFireBase();
  //This object "metodos" is of a class that has several reusable methods:
  Metodos metodos = new Metodos();

  @override
  void initState() {
    objetoSentencias.obtenerVacaciones(_noEmpleado).then((resultados){
      setState(() {
        vacaciones = resultados;
      });
    });
  }
  ...
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
  ...
  RichText(
    text: TextSpan(
      //toDateTime is a method that converts a timestamp into a DateTime, 
      //and then converts the DateTime into a String with a specific date format.
      //'Inicio' stores a timestamp (it is the date on which the holidays start):
      text: metodos.toDateTime(vacaciones.documents[0].data['Inicio']),
      style: TextStyle(
        color: Colors.black,
        fontSize: 30,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
      ),
    )
  )
  ...
}
```

This is the error message:
flutter: ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY. 
╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
flutter: The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building   StreamBuilder(dirty, state:
flutter: _StreamBuilderBaseState>#45dbd):
flutter: The getter 'documents' was called on null
flutter: Receiver: null
flutter: Tried calling: documents

Note:
I was wrong to put the reference of the document, it was not "Turnos":

```
return await Firestore.instance.document('Turnos/$empleado');
```

but "Vacaciones":

```
return await Firestore.instance.document('Vacaciones/$empleado');
```

(I updated it in the question) but in any case it does not "affect" what in itself is the question.

Answer (score 0):

you have mention collection name to access specific document record, then if you have multiple record you can use forEach to retrieve docuemntId from each iterative record.

In your case just try to add collection name before document. like below code.

```
 Firestore.instance
    .collection('collection')
    .document(newCategory.field1)
    ....
});
```

Comment: You can pass the entire path into a call to `document(...)`, so in OP's code (`document('Turnos/$empleado')`), there is a collection `Turnos` and a document `$empleado`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're calling `document()`, the result is going to be a single document. But in your `build` method, you're trying to get a document out of a collection:

```
text: metodos.toDateTime(vacaciones.documents[0].data['Inicio']),
```

Since `vacaciones` is a single document, this should be something like:

```
text: metodos.toDateTime(vacaciones.data['Inicio']),
```

Comment: And what kind of variable would have to be "vacaciones" to be able to display the information?  

In my code I have it defined as "QuerySnapshot" as shown below:  
`QuerySnapshot vacaciones;` 
and when I want to use the syntax that you mention to me, it marks me an error:  

"The getter 'data' is not defined for the class 'QuerySnapshot'"

Comment: That would be a [`DocumentSnapshot`](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentSnapshot-class.html). For cases like this I highly recommend keeping the [reference documentation](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore-library.html) handy.

Comment: I already change the type of variable that is "vacaciones" to `DocumentSnapshot` and now I get this new error: "The getter 'data' was called on null".

The first thing I thought was that my service to get the information from the document was wrong, but if I use the same document reference in a stream builder as it is: `stream: Firestore.instance.document ('Vacaciones/$_noEmpleado'). Snapshots ( )`, which allows me to show the information, which already solves my problem, but even so I want to know why in the other way I get that error.